# Ms Excel VBA type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, exception, types, mismatch

I am receiving type mismatch error when I use below mentioned code.If possible please help to resolve below mentioned code error.Both AP# and AR3 have charactor values.

What my basic requirment is use function just like concatenate function to add two charactor values from two cell in one excel cell using vba code

```
Range("AI3:AI" & lrv + 2).Value = Range("AP3:AP" & lrv + 2).Value & " " & Range("AR3:AR" & lrv + 2).Value
```

Comment: What does "A13:AI"&Irv evaluate to when you debug?

Comment: I am receiving type mismatch error

Comment: What is in Irv? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: lrv = Sheets("Vendor").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Secondly AR3 values are given below    Range("AR3").Formula = "=""Fragrances Name: ""&IFERROR(IF(T3<>"""",T3,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""By"",LEFT(G3,SEARCH("" "",G3,SEARCH("" "",G3,1)+1))))<>FALSE,LEFT(G3,FIND("" "",G3,1)-1),LEFT(G3,SEARCH("" "",G3,SEARCH("" "",G3,1)+1)))),"""")"
Range("AR3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AR3:AR" & lrv + 2), Type:=xlFillDefault
   Range("AR3:AR" & lrv + 2).Select
  Selection.Copy
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: What my requirement is just asin values of AR3 and some other colum value to AI3.Just like concatenate function in VBA

Comment: @tahir Please don't post code in comments, _edit_ your question to include the additional infomation.  And be sure to use a `Code Block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a mismatch error because this is an incorrect way of assigning values. For example, this is incorrect

```
Range("D1:D3").Value = Range("A1:A3").Value & " " & Range("B1:B3").Value
```

You are working with array. So try this

```
Range("D1:D3").FormulaArray = _
"=(" & Range("A1:A3").Address & ") & "" "" & (" & Range("B1:B3").Address & ")"
```

So your code becomes

```
Range("AI3:AI" & lrv + 2).FormulaArray = _
"=(" & _
Range("AP3:AP" & lrv + 2).Address & _
") & "" "" & (" & _
Range("AR3:AR" & lrv + 2).Address & ")"
```

Or in a more simplified manner

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

Set rng1 = Range("AI3:AI" & lrv + 2)
Set rng2 = Range("AP3:AP" & lrv + 2)
Set rng3 = Range("AR3:AR" & lrv + 2)

rng1.FormulaArray = "=(" & _
                    rng2.Address & _
                    ") "" "" & (" & _
                    rng3.Address & _
                    ")"

rng1.Value = rng1.Value

rng2.Resize(1,2).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,one last question,Is this possible that after assigning values from AP3 and AR3 set AP3 and AQ3=blank,i mean set values in both field equals to null

Comment: Actully i create values in AP3 and AQ3 on temprary basis just to use in AI3 and after that i want to clear both fields but when i clear both fields then there is no value in AI3

Comment: Yes, you use `rng2.Resize(1,2).ClearContents`. This set AP3 and AQ3 to blank. I reference this to sid's simplified manner.

Comment: @ tahir mybad, i thought you already figure turning AI3 to values. Sid already provided that :) @sid np dude, i saw the OP is still waiting so i lend a hand. Too bad i did not anticipate AI3 hehe.